# PHP throwing permission denied error for a files in a directory

Tags: centos, php, permissions

Recently I moved a site from Ubuntu to Centos and began to notice that users were displayed a blank response page after performing transactions. The Apache logs had these messages.

```
[Mon Jul 15 02:15:58 2013] [error] [client 173.24.242.72] PHP Warning:  file_put_contents(/home/sridhar/public_html/mysite.com/public/pgway_icici/dompdf/lib/fonts/php_Helvetica.afm): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /home/sridhar/public_html/mysite.com/public/pgway_icici/dompdf/lib/class.pdf.php on line 2354
[Mon Jul 15 02:15:58 2013] [error] [client 173.24.242.72] PHP Warning:  file_put_contents(/home/sridhar/public_html/mysite.com/public/pgway_icici/dompdf/lib/fonts/php_Helvetica-Bold.afm): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /home/sridhar/public_html/mysite.com/public/pgway_icici/dompdf/lib/class.pdf.php on line 2354
[Mon Jul 15 02:15:58 2013] [error] [client 173.24.242.72] PHP Warning:  file_put_contents(/home/sridhar/public_html/mysite.com/public/pgway_icici/dompdf/lib/fonts/php_Helvetica-Bold.afm): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /home/sridhar/public_html/mysite.com/public/pgway_icici/dompdf/lib/class.pdf.php on line 2354
[Mon Jul 15 02:15:58 2013] [error] [client 173.24.242.72] PHP Warning:  file_put_contents(/home/sridhar/public_html/mysite.com/public/pgway_icici/dompdf/lib/fonts/php_Helvetica-Bold.afm): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /home/sridhar/public_html/mysite.com/public/pgway_icici/dompdf/lib/class.pdf.php on line 2354
[Mon Jul 15 02:15:58 2013] [error] [client 173.24.242.72] PHP Warning:  file_put_contents(/home/sridhar/public_html/mysite.com/public/pgway_icici/dompdf/lib/fonts/php_Helvetica.afm): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /home/sridhar/public_html/mysite.com/public/pgway_icici/dompdf/lib/class.pdf.php on line 2354
[Mon Jul 15 02:15:58 2013] [error] [client 173.24.242.72] PHP Warning:  file_put_contents(/home/sridhar/public_html/mysite.com/public/pgway_icici/dompdf/lib/fonts/php_Helvetica.afm): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /home/sridhar/public_html/mysite.com/public/pgway_icici/dompdf/lib/class.pdf.php on line 2354
```

Checking ls -lZ for each of these directories I had the following outputs

```
[root@i-8941-35408-VM pgway_icici]# ls -lZ dompdf
-rw-r--r--  1001 1001 user_u:object_r:httpd_sys_content_t ChangeLog
-rw-r--r--  1001 1001 user_u:object_r:httpd_sys_content_t dompdf_config.inc.php
-rw-r--r--  1001 1001 user_u:object_r:httpd_sys_content_t dompdf.php
-rw-r--r--  1001 1001 user_u:object_r:httpd_sys_content_t HACKING
drwxr-xr-x  1001 1001 user_u:object_r:httpd_sys_content_t include
-rw-r--r--  1001 1001 user_u:object_r:httpd_sys_content_t INSTALL
drwxr-xr-x  1001 1001 user_u:object_r:httpd_sys_content_t lib
-rw-r--r--  1001 1001 user_u:object_r:httpd_sys_content_t LICENSE.LGPL
-rw-r--r--  1001 1001 user_u:object_r:httpd_sys_content_t load_font.php
-rw-r--r--  1001 1001 user_u:object_r:httpd_sys_content_t README
-rw-r--r--  1001 1001 user_u:object_r:httpd_sys_content_t TODO
[root@i-8941-35408-VM pgway_icici]# ls -lZ dompdf/lib
-rw-r--r--  1001 1001 user_u:object_r:httpd_sys_content_t class.pdf.php
drwxr-xr-x  1001 1001 user_u:object_r:httpd_sys_content_t fonts
drwxr-xr-x  1001 1001 user_u:object_r:httpd_sys_content_t res
[root@i-8941-35408-VM pgway_icici]# ls -lZ dompdf/lib/fonts
-rw-r--r--  1001 1001 user_u:object_r:httpd_sys_content_t Courier.afm
-rw-r--r--  1001 1001 user_u:object_r:httpd_sys_content_t Courier-Bold.afm
-rw-r--r--  1001 1001 user_u:object_r:httpd_sys_content_t Courier-BoldOblique.afm
-rw-r--r--  1001 1001 user_u:object_r:httpd_sys_content_t Courier-Oblique.afm
-rw-r--r--  1001 1001 user_u:object_r:httpd_sys_content_t dompdf_font_family_cache
-rw-r--r--  1001 1001 user_u:object_r:httpd_sys_content_t dompdf_font_family_cache.dist
-rw-r--r--  1001 1001 user_u:object_r:httpd_sys_content_t Helvetica.afm
-rw-r--r--  1001 1001 user_u:object_r:httpd_sys_content_t Helvetica-Bold.afm
-rw-r--r--  1001 1001 user_u:object_r:httpd_sys_content_t Helvetica-BoldOblique.afm
-rw-r--r--  1001 1001 user_u:object_r:httpd_sys_content_t Helvetica-Oblique.afm
-rw-r--r--  1001 1001 user_u:object_r:httpd_sys_content_t Times-Bold.afm
-rw-r--r--  1001 1001 user_u:object_r:httpd_sys_content_t Times-BoldItalic.afm
-rw-r--r--  1001 1001 user_u:object_r:httpd_sys_content_t Times-Italic.afm
-rw-r--r--  1001 1001 user_u:object_r:httpd_sys_content_t Times-Roman.afm
-rw-r--r--  1001 1001 user_u:object_r:httpd_sys_content_t ZapfDingbats.afm
```

Not sure what could be wrong. Would appreciate any suggestions to resolve this.

Comment: By the way the response page is th eonly problem. The site runs fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These files are not owned by apache, so, you'll need to chmod the fonts/*.afm files to +w to other in order to give write permissions to apache (`chmod 666 fonts/*.afm`). Alternatively, give the ownership to apache (`chown apache fonts/*.afm`).

Might also want to set proper file ownership to all of these. As it seems to be unable to find the username to these user# 1001.